# Trying to make quicksort faster by using insertionsort

Tags: java, hashmap, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement a method that sorts an arraylist of keys (in descending fashion) using a quicksort algorithm.

This is for an assignment, so we are only allowed to use java.util.ArrayList, java.util.HashMap, and java.util.Map.Entry (though I'm sure other tools could be used to do this way easier).

I'm trying to speed up my QuickSort algorithm by using InsertionSort for the smaller lists, but I'm getting wrong values for the ordering when I do so. I'm certain there's something wrong with the InsertionSort but I'm not really sure what. Help would be appreciated!

The specific Insertion Sort method is below:

```
private static <K extends Comparable<K>> void insertionSort(ArrayList<K> elements, int beg, int end){
    for (int i = beg + 1; i <= end; i++){
        K currentElement = elements.get(i);

        while (i >= beg && elements.get(i).compareTo(currentElement) < 0){
            elements.set(i+1, elements.get(i));
            i--;
        }
        elements.set(i+1,currentElement);
    }
```

The entire code (including the quicksort) is below:

```
//public method to return an array list containing all keys, quickly ordered in descending order
public static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> ArrayList<K> fastSort(HashMap<K, V> results)
{
    //create a new array list of type K to store the ordered key list in
    ArrayList<K> sortedUrls = new ArrayList<K>();

    //insert all the keys of the specified hash map to the new list
    sortedUrls.addAll(results.keySet());

    //call the quicksort method to sort the array list
    quicksort(sortedUrls,0, sortedUrls.size()-1);

    return sortedUrls;
}

private static <K extends Comparable<K>> void swap(ArrayList<K> elements, int i, int j){
    //Method to swap 2 elements in an arraylist
    K temp = elements.get(i);
    elements.set(i, elements.get(j));
    elements.set(j, temp);
}

private static <K extends Comparable<K>> void quicksort(ArrayList<K> elements, int beg, int end){
    //make sure that beginning and end indexes are proper
    if(beg>=end) return;
    if(beg<0) return;
    if(end>elements.size()-1) return;

    int size = (end+1 - beg);

    //incorporating InsertionSort for smaller lists
    if (size <= 10){
        insertionSort(elements, beg, end);
    }

    //else use QuickSort for larger lists
    else {
        //update the pivot and swap appropriate elements using the partition helper method
        int pivot = partition(elements, beg, end);

        //recursively call quicksort on either side of the pivot
        quicksort(elements, beg, pivot - 1);
        quicksort(elements, pivot + 1, end);
    }
    //}
}

private static <K extends Comparable<K>> int partition(ArrayList<K> elements, int beg, int end){

    //Get a random pivot between beg and end
    int random = beg + (int)Math.random()*(elements.size())/(end-beg+1);

    //New position of pivot element
    int last=end;

    //Move the pivot element to right edge of the array
    swap(elements, random, end);
    end--;

    while(beg<=end){
        if(elements.get(beg).compareTo(elements.get(last)) > 0) beg++; //Accumulate smaller elements to the left
        else {
            swap(elements, beg, end);
            end--;
        }
    }

    //Move pivot element to its correct position
    swap(elements, beg, last);

    return beg;
}

private static <K extends Comparable<K>> void insertionSort(ArrayList<K> elements, int beg, int end){
    for (int i = beg + 1; i <= end; i++){
        K currentElement = elements.get(i);

        while (i >= beg && elements.get(i).compareTo(currentElement) < 0){
            elements.set(i+1, elements.get(i));
            i--;
        }
        elements.set(i+1,currentElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: The entire code should have the class identifier, the imports, and the main method. You just have a large code fragment here.

Comment: @khelwood I think that's what I have to do to sort it in descending order right?

Comment: I didn't spot that. Try writing some unit tests.